# Can't use SUM inside ARRAYFORMULA

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, multidimensional-array, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I just confused about what I'm doing wrong
I use ARRAYFORMULA just to sum every range in a row like this

```
={
"Manager Result";
ARRAYFORMULA(
SUM(D2:D,H2:H)
)
}
```

But I get this instead

[image]

When I use it like this

```
={
"Manager Result";
ARRAYFORMULA(D2:D+H2:H)
}
```

Everything is OK

[image]

But I still can't get why I can't use SUM inside ARRAYFORMULA.

The second trouble is I'd like to place the same number in one column but it also doesn't work so I get an error:

> "Circular dependency detected. To resolve with iterative calculation,
> see File > Spreadsheet Settings."

```
    ={
"Max Result 
(Basic --> total count of 3 marks)";
ARRAYFORMULA(J2:J=15)
}
```

[image]

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SUM` is not supported under `ARRAYFORMULA`. you can either use ranges like you did `D2:D+H2:H` or use `MMULT` function which is able to perform all 4 kinds of operation `+ - ÷ ×`

in your case it would be:

```
={"Manager Result"; ARRAYFORMULA(MMULT({A2:A6, C2:C6}, {1;1}^0))}
```

[image]

see:
**https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/mmult-function-in-google-sheets/**

Answer (score 2):

alternative:

```
={"Manager Result"; BYROW({A2:A6, C2:C6}; LAMBDA(x; SUM(x)))}
```